# User Sign Up Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, apache, authentication, nullpointerexception

I am building a chat application in Android with backend MySQL, PHP nand running on local network with Apache. However, as a uses attempts to sign up, the LogCat displays a Nullpoint error on line 112, at "public void run()".

I have reviewed the code multiple times but cannot locate why a null point error persists...any siuggestions?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.baidar.androidChatter.interfacer.Manager;
import com.baidar.androidChatter.serve.MessagingService;


public class SigningUp extends Activity {

    private static final int FILL_ALL_FIELDS = 0;
    protected static final int TYPE_SAME_PASSWORD_IN_PASSWORD_FIELDS = 1;
    private static final int SIGN_UP_FAILED = 9;
    private static final int SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED = 3;
    private static final int SIGN_UP_SUCCESSFULL = 4;
    protected static final int USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_LENGTH_SHORT = 5;


    //private static final String SERVER_RES_SIGN_UP_FAILED = "0";
    private static final String SERVER_RES_RES_SIGN_UP_SUCCESFULL = "1";
    private static final String SERVER_RES_SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED = "2";



    private EditText usernameText;
    private EditText passwordText;
    private EditText eMailText;
    private EditText passwordAgainText;
    private Manager imService;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {


        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            // This is called when the connection with the service has been
            // established, giving us the service object we can use to
            // interact with the service.  Because we have bound to a explicit
            // service that we know is running in our own process, we can
            // cast its IBinder to a concrete class and directly access it.
            imService = ((MessagingService.IMBinder)service).getService();  


        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            // This is called when the connection with the service has been
            // unexpectedly disconnected -- that is, its process crashed.
            // Because it is running in our same process, we should never
            // see this happen.
            imService = null;
            Toast.makeText(SigningUp.this, R.string.local_service_stopped,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    



            setContentView(R.layout.signingup);
            setTitle("Sign up");

            Button signUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signUp);
            Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_signUp);
            usernameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
            passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);  
            passwordAgainText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordAgain);  
            eMailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

            signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {                       
                    if (usernameText.length() > 0 &&        
                        passwordText.length() > 0 && 
                        passwordAgainText.length() > 0 &&
                        eMailText.length() > 0
                        )
                    {
                        //TODO check email address is valid

                        if (passwordText.getText().toString().equals(passwordAgainText.getText().toString())){

                            if (usernameText.length() >= 5 && passwordText.length() >= 5) {

                                    Thread thread = new Thread(){
                                        String result = new String();
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            result = imService.signUpUser(usernameText.getText().toString(), 
                                                    passwordText.getText().toString(), 
                                                    eMailText.getText().toString());

                                            handler.post(new Runnable(){

                                                public void run() {
                                                    if (result.equals(SERVER_RES_RES_SIGN_UP_SUCCESFULL)) {
                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.signup_successfull, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                        //showDialog(SIGN_UP_SUCCESSFULL);
                                                    }
                                                    else if (result.equals(SERVER_RES_SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED)){
                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.signup_username_crashed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                        //showDialog(SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED);
                                                    }
                                                    else  //if (result.equals(SERVER_RES_SIGN_UP_FAILED)) 
                                                    {
                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.signup_failed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                        //showDialog(SIGN_UP_FAILED);
                                                    }           
                                                }

                                            });
                                        }

                                    };
                                    thread.start();
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.username_and_password_length_short, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                //showDialog(USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_LENGTH_SHORT);
                            }                           
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.signup_type_same_password_in_password_fields, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //showDialog(TYPE_SAME_PASSWORD_IN_PASSWORD_FIELDS);
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.signup_fill_all_fields, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //showDialog(FILL_ALL_FIELDS);

                    }               
                }           
            });

            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {                       
                    finish();                   
                }               
            });


        }


    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
    {       

        switch (id) 
        {
            case TYPE_SAME_PASSWORD_IN_PASSWORD_FIELDS:         
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SigningUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.signup_type_same_password_in_password_fields)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })        
                .create();          
            case FILL_ALL_FIELDS:               
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SigningUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.signup_fill_all_fields)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })        
                .create();
            case SIGN_UP_FAILED:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SigningUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.signup_failed)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })        
                .create();
            case SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SigningUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.signup_username_crashed)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })        
                .create();
            case SIGN_UP_SUCCESSFULL:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SigningUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.signup_successfull)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })        
                .create();  
            case USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_LENGTH_SHORT:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SigningUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.username_and_password_length_short)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })        
                .create();
            default:
                return null;

        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        bindService(new Intent(SigningUp.this, MessagingService.class), mConnection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        super.onPause();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey your problem is because of ImService object. its declaration in onResume method just move it to your onCreate because oncreate call before onresume method and your imService object use in oncreate.

bindService(new Intent(SigningUp.this, MessagingService.class), mConnection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

put this line before buttononclicklistner.

Comment: The only thing that appears in onResume is:  bindService(new Intent(SigningUp.this, MessagingService.class), mConnection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        super.onResume();   There is not ImService object

Comment: yes but its binds your ServiceConnection class object and that class initialize ImService object. so your connection class must bind before its contain object use. understend?

Comment: hi i found mistake its not in bind service

Comment: but it is in  if (result.equals(SERVER_RES_RES_SIGN_UP_SUCCESFULL)) { line first log your result if result represent null then you cant directly check it with string. your condition must be  if (result!= null && result.equals(SERVER_RES_RES_SIGN_UP_SUCCESFULL)) { thats it...

Comment: and one more thing when you declare your handler object. it not in code so first declare handler object

Comment: Your changes, aside from adding the handler object, simply moved the nullpointer to line 121 at result.equals(SERVER_RES_SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED

Comment: then put result!= null in that condition too...same as above if condtion.

Comment: That handled the app crashing, but why is the "result" value always null?

Comment: thats itbeacuse you get null from imService.signUpUser(...) method check it.why it gives you null.

Comment: I guess that solved the problem, now I have connection issues but app no longer crashes as user sign up